# invisible <a> appears on the bottom of my clickable image icons, how to get rid of it?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I created a couple of small clickable image "buttons"

This is how they look

[image: The "buttons"]

This is the range of their margin

[image: margin1] [image: margin2]

This is the clickable "a" at the bottom of the buttons that i want to get rid of

Some of it is inside the margin shown above

It's a separate "a" tag cut off from the actual tag that's only clickable inside the border of those buttons

[image: weird] [image: weird 2]

Creation file (react):

```
const Smallbuttons = () => {
return (
<div id="smallbuttons">
  <a
    href="https://github.com/"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
  >
    <img id="github" src={require("./github.png")} alt="Github" />
  </a>
  <a
    href="https://www.linkedin.com/"
    target="_blank"
    rel="noopener noreferrer"
  >
    <img id="linkedin" src={require("./linkedin.png")} alt="LinkedIn" />
  </a>
</div>
);
};

export default Smallbuttons;
```

CSS file:

```
#github, #linkedin {
margin: 2rem 1rem;
height: 3vh;
width: auto;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid white;
padding: 0.3rem;
cursor: pointer;
}

#smallbuttons img:hover {
border: 1px solid #d4af37;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them in an unordered list like this. The reason that's happening because you're resizing the child which is the image here and that makes the parent `a` takes the size of it `img`. So by resizing the `a` instead, it should be fine.

JS

```js
      <div id="smallbuttons">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              <img id="github" src={require("./github.png")} alt="Github" />
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
              <img id="linkedin" src={require("./linkedin.png")} alt="LinkedIn" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

CSS

```css
#smallbuttons{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 200;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
#smallbuttons ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
#smallbuttons ul li a {
  width: auto;
  height: 3vh;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
 }

#github, #linkedin {
  height: inherit;
  width: auto;
}
```